# How do I select two max values for two categories for each year in a year range?

Tags: mysql, windows

1st time asking on stack overflow.

I'm trying to calculate the leader in OPS for the NL and AL for each year in a year range range using two tables, one with batting statistics and one with the names of the players. The primary key for the tables is playerID

The batting table provides that batting statistic information. I inserted columns calculating OPS, on-base percentage, slugging, average to the batting table, but I want to choose the top leader in each of those categories for each league (AL,NL) in a year range.

My code so far is:

```
SELECT 
    batting.YearID as 'Year'
  , batting.LGID as 'League'
  , (SELECT concat(NAMEFIRST, ' ', NAMELAST) 
     from master 
     WHERE playerID = batting.playerID
    ) AS 'Player'
  , max(OPS) as 'On-Base Plus Slugging'
FROM batting 
WHERE batting.yearID BETWEEN 1959 AND 1969 
  AND AB > (SELECT AVG(AB) FROM BATTING)
GROUP BY batting.YearID, batting.lgID
```

My output is just the first player in the alphabet for each league, for each year. My goal is to find the leader in OPS from each league for each year in the year range.  I've tried a few different groupings, but can't seem to get this to work. Can anyone assist?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. Please tag RDMBS you are using.

Comment: Can a player get transferred between leagues during the season? If so you may need to consider that possibility.

Comment: I'm only somewhat following, can you provide a small sample of your tables and data, and a desired result? Also since you provided what you tried (which is fantastic), what is it showing you?

Comment: This is something about baseball, right? See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 or newer:

```
;WITH ORDERED_OPS AS(
SELECT PlayerID,
    YearID,
    LGID,
    OPS,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LGID ORDER BY OPS DESC) OPS_Order
FROM batting)
SELECT PlayerID,
 YearID,
    LGID,
    OPS
FROM ORDERED_OPS
WHERE OPS_Order = 1
```

Comment: SQL Server 2010??? There is no such thing. This query would work as early as 2005 when both the cte and the ROW_NUMBER function were added.